# run script in background(shell_exec) fails on composer/PHP-DI function

Tags: php

I run that script manually and everything works,

```
$container = require '../config/bootstrap.php';

    try {
       $test  = $container->get(Test::class);
       $test->run();

    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        die;
    }
```

but when I call that file from another folder like the following :

```
$script = __DIR__ .'/folder/test-service.php';
$output = shell_exec('php '.$script);
var_dump($output);
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../config/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:') in /anotherFolder/folder/test-service.php on line 13

and also after that, I got a lot of error that files do not exist.

bootstrap.php include the class mapping of PHP-DI

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

```
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder;
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
$container = $containerBuilder->build();
return $container;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` instruction is relative to your current directory.

You could replace the line with `require __DIR__.'/../config/bootstrap.php';`